# Using fitted ARIMA model to forecast new time series

Tags: forecasting, arima

I'm new to ARIMA analysis and I'm trying to understand how fitted ARIMA model can be used to forecast new time series, given starting point only. Should the model be refitted or the estimated parameters are sufficient to produce forecasts? Thanks

Comment: For an ARIMA model (p,d,q) You will need at least as many past observations as the maximum of p+d or q, i.e. it depends on the order of lagged terms in the model.